# DropDownList Value gets duplicated when updating inside GridView from Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

There are three values in column1 DropDownList inside a Grid View from the database for `example: A, B and C.`
On the `Grid View`'s `DropDownList` when I click on Update to change `A to B`, then A disappears from the database and B gets duplicated and then three values show in the dropdownList B,B and C. If I select B again then three values show B ,B and B. I tried using `AutoPostBack="True"` but still this is happening. What's the problem in the HTML?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
     DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="column1" DataValueField="column1"
     SelectedValue='<%# Bind("column1") %>'>         
</asp:DropDownList>
```

SQL:

```
 UPDATE Command:
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [tblInventory] SET [Part#] = @column1,
                   [Description] = @Description, 
                   [Qty] = @Qty, [Brand] = @Brand, 
                   [ItemType#] = @column2 WHERE [ID] = @ID">
```

Comment: since we can't see anything more than the markup that you have posted perhaps you could set breakpoints in your codebehind and evaluate each of the values one by one when inside of the onchange or click event.. can you show you code in regards to what event you are in..? also show us your `UPDATE` Code

Comment: https://khanrahim.wordpress.com/2010/04/13/combobox-with-datagridview-in-c/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that one database table is being used and same column is being updated. Add another table and bind it as a DropDownList.